# How to embed a whole project into a phar file?

Tags: php, phar

I have my `index.php` that uses a class inside a php library  (including folders, classes, subclasses) etc..

my index.php uses that whole library

```
...
include("Classes/Crawler.php");
$crawl = new Crawler(); // 
...
```

1. Is there a simple command line to create the phar files that includes all content inside Classes ?
2. Do I need then to modify content of files so I can use index.php as it was ?

My goal is to distribute 2 files (index.php and Crawler.phar) without having to changing the source code

Comment: There are lots of tools for that; plain `phar pack -f`, `empir` or `box`, or `phpab` in your case, else `phar-composer`, `xpm` perhaps. You'll need to elaborate on how the index script interacts with the classes, or vice versa.

Comment: index.php just instanties a class and call soem methods like:
$crawl->start();

Comment: Use http://phpab.net/ then. Bakes a nice autoloader into the phar, which happens to be fully PHP-compliant.

Answer (score 1):

I use phing's `pharpackage` task to build my phar files, see https://github.com/cweiske/phorkie/blob/master/build.xml#L82 for an example.

But apart from that, you can write your own script (it's easy; [see the examples](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.buildfromdirectory.php) in the PHP manual).

---

About using `index.php` as it was: You can do that as long as you enable file interception with [Phar::interceptFileFuncs()](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.interceptfilefuncs.php).